# If not disabled do this

Tags: jquery, math

I am adding numbers entered into some inputs and getting a total. The totaling script works however now I want to not included the inputs to be counted if they are disabled. I am thinking I need to use :not(:disabled) but not sure how to put it into my script properly?

This is the script that counts:

```
$('.observationPositive').each(function(){
    countP++;
    sumP += Number($(this).val());
});
```

How do I say only count if not disabled? (wrongly coded example)

```
$('.observationPositive').each(function(){
    countP++;
    sumP += Number($(this:not(:disabled)).val());
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Only iterate over the ones that aren't disabled:

```
$('.observationPositive:not(:disabled)').each(function() {
   // increment count
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Your selector needs to be a string:

```
 $(this).is(":not(:disabled)");
```

This will return a boolean though. Calling `val` on a jQuery selector that matches no elements will return `undefined` and if you add `undefined` to a number you get `NaN`.

```
sumP += $(this).is(":disabled") ? 0 : Number($(this).val());
```

In your particular case [Jivings' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14569089/1290545) is better.

Answer (score 1):

Add your constraints to the main selector :

```
$('.observationPositive:not(:disabled)').each(function(){
    countP++;
    sumP += Number($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Even more simple:

```
 !$(this).is(":disabled");
```